# Exclusion script syntax

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, exclusion-script

I'm trying to add an exclusion script into a Journey so I can exclude the users from a DE.
The DE that I want to exclude has only one field, Email and is PK.

This is the script that I'm adding under the Exclusion Script in the Journey

```
 ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("JourneyScriptExclusion","Email", @Email))>0
```

I'm doing some testing now but when I activated the Journey it didn't exclude the email from the source DE. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I find it easier to test exclusion scripts in the body of the email before adding it to the send definition.  Something like this.

```ampscript
%%[

output(concat("<br>email", @email)) 

if ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("JourneyScriptExclusion","Email", @Email))>0 then
  output(concat("<br>excluded"))
else
  output(concat("<br>sending"))
endif
  
]%%
```

Answer (score 2):

I would fetch the email value like this in the exclusion script instead of using the AMpscript variable. Try this:

```
ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("JourneyScriptExclusion","Email", AttributeValue("Your email field name")))>0
```

Comment: +1 `AttributeValue("emailaddr")` should always have a value on an email send.